# 'chmod -644' would set file permission to 000

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I had a file with 644(`-rw-r--r--`) and wanted to change it to 664(`-rw-rw-r--`), after running:

```
sudo chmod -664 my_file
```

file permissions were set to 000(`----------`).

Trying to change the permissions to anything different than 000 seems to be not working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Why do you have a `-` in front of 644 ? Try `sudo chmod 644 my_file`. `-644` will remove the rights.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You are using `-664`, just use `664` instead. And *never* use `sudo` when you don't need to. If that's your file, you don't need `sudo`:

```
chmod 644 my_file
```

When you run `chmod` with a `-` before the mode, you will remove that mode. See `man chmod` (emphasis mine):

> The operator + causes the selected file mode bits to be added  to
> the  existing file  mode  bits of each file; **- causes them to be
> removed**; and = causes them to    be added and causes unmentioned bits
> to be removed except that a directory's unmentioned set user and
> group ID bits are not affected.

The numbers are:

- 1: execute
- 2: write
- 4: read

So a file with `777` permissions means everyone has the right to do all three, since 1 + 2 + 4 = 7, and therefore setting the permissions to 7 means allowing read, write and execute.

If you start with a file whose mode is `777`:

```
$ ls -l my_file 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 terdon terdon 0 May 28 13:45 my_file
```

And now run `chmod -644`, you will remove the bits `644`, and end up with a file whose mode is `133`:

```
$ chmod -644 my_file; ls -l my_file 
---x-wx-wx 1 terdon terdon 0 May 28 13:45 my_file
```

That's because you removed 6 (read (4) + write (2)) from the owner's permissions, leaving only 1 (execute) set, and 4 (read) from the group and other permissions. The result is a file with only execute (1) permissions for the owner, and write and execute (you unset 4, leaving 1 and 3) permissions for the rest.

Because your file presumably had the default permissions for new files, so `644`, when you ran `chmod -644 my_file`, you removed all of the set permission bits and got a file with no permissions for anybody.

```
$ ls -l my_file 
-rw-r--r-- 1 terdon terdon 0 May 28 13:45 my_file
$ chmod -644 my_file
$ ls -l my_file 
---------- 1 terdon terdon 0 May 28 13:45 my_file
```